# dyld: Library not loaded when trying to run Fortran executable from Objective-C using NSTask

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

This may be a little unusual but I have a program written in Fortran which accepts some command line arguments and performs a simulation. Now I'd like to add a GUI written in Xcode to run the executable and give it some command line arguments. I compile the Fortran program using the command-line and then try to run it in Xcode like this:

```
   NSString * path = @"path/to/executable";
   NSArray * args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"arg1",@"arg2", nil];

   [NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:path arguments:args] waitUntilExit];
```

However, when I run it I get:  `libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib dyld: Library not loaded. Reason: image not found.` The libraries are set in my .profile and work/link fine from the command line but from Xcode it doesn't work. I even tried statically linking it by copying the .a and compiling my program with that to no avail.

As per request, the output of otool -L:

```
   lnew-host:$ otool -L /Users/username/Desktop/Simulation/Sim

/Users/username/Desktop/Simulation/Sim:
    libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    libmkl_intel_thread.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    libmkl_core.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    libiomp5.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libfgsl.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

Comment: Show the output of `otool -L /path/to/executable`.

Comment: @trojanfoe I added it to my main post

Comment: I'd like to see the results of running `otool -L` on the executable, not the `.dylib` (though that is useful).

Comment: @trojanfoe That's what I did (I think), I ran -otool -L /path/to/executable

Comment: @trojanfoe I accidentally left out the first line on my copy/paste by accident if that's what you mean, it's fixed now. I ran it on the actual executable Fortran program, not the dylib and this is the output.

Comment: OK so where are `libmkl_xxx.dylib` located in the filesytem relative to the executable?  They look like they are in the same directory?

Comment: @trojanfoe the .dylib files are located in /opt/intel/mkl/lib

Comment: OK, well that `otool` output implies those intel `.dylib`s cannot be found and that executable should fail to run from both the shell and from `NSTask`.  Yet you claim the executable runs OK, which I don't understand.

Comment: @trojanfoe I have the dyld_library_path set in my .profile and runs fine from command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue relates to the mechanism used to resolve the `.dylib` paths.

When running it from the command line you are resolving the path by setting the environment variable `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

When running via `NSTask` you *aren't doing anything at all* (Xcode won't inherit the environment you set in `.profile`; in fact how any app, not invoked using `/usr/bin/open`, gets its environment is pretty complicated).

The best long term solution to this issue is to use `install_name_tool` to fix the location of each of the Intel libraries in the executable:

```
cd /Users/username/Desktop/Simulation
for lib in libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib libmkl_intel_thread.dylib libmkl_core.dylib 
do
    install_name_tool -change $lib /opt/intel/mkl/lib/$lib Sim
done
```

This change is permanent and means there is no need to use `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` any more, however if you built `Sim` then this can all be done when linking it.

Now if you intend to package your GUI for sale on the App Store (or even Ad Hoc distribution) then you are going to need to package those libraries in with the app bundle and you have even more work to do to get that right.  But that's another story isn't it.

Bottom line: Using `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is always a bad idea under any version of *NIX (for Linux use `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` and for OSX use `install_name_tool`).

Comment: This is good to know. I did this for each library in my executable and then I had to actually do the same for one of the libraries that was referencing one of the other libraries. I also found a compiler option -static-intel, that statically links Intel libraries. Not sure which one I'll use.